# how to make aws public ip run on https on port 80 for nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, https

I have hosted my node.js app on AWS EC2.

I don't have a domain name for my nodejs app. I am running it on Public IPv4 address `54.242.85.178`.

I have a domain for my front end and its running on https so when https and http comes I am getting the following error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.wixten.com/query/622c64b4a12ed5002313daf5' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://54.242.85.178/answersapi/622c64b4a12ed5002313daf5'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: You should not do that. On a public node, https is (should always be) always on port 443. This isn't 100% true, but it's close enough. One thing you would never do, is publish https on port 80, which is reserved for http.

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error, your frontend is making `HTTPS` calls to an `HTTP` endpoint (on the ip `54.242.85.178`), hence you have that error. I am guessing you're using ajax to make that call.

For a quick fix, you can update your frontend to make `HTTP` calls to your backend, This will sort out this issue, however this is **HIGHLY NOT** recommended but it will help you understand the issue better.

Ideally, you have to add an SSL certificate on your backend as well, then you can make `HTTPS` calls to it from your frontend.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all - you **can't mix https and http**. You have to go through your source code and eliminate all http urls and substitute them for proper https urls.